# Can we use ssh to connect to a web server and then send a http request and receive a http response?

Tags: ssh, webserver, telnet

```
telnet www.ietf.org 80
GET /rfc.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.ietf.org
```

This sequence of commands starts up a telnet (i.e., TCP) connection to port 80 on
IETF’s Web server, www.ietf.org. Then comes the GET command naming the
path of the URL and the protocol. Try servers and URLs of your choosing. The
next line is the mandatory Host header.

1. Can we use `ssh` instead of `telnet`, something like

   ```
   ssh www.ietf.org 80
   GET /rfc.html HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.ietf.org
   ```

   ?
2. What **other programs** besides `ssh` can be used in place of `telnet` in the above
   example to establish a connection from a local host to a remote http
   server, so that we can send a http request to the http server and
   receive a http response from it?

   What **kind of programs** can be used in place of `telent` in the above example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ssh`, as the SSH clients awaits for some banner from the server, before proceeding with server host key check, ... The SSH protocol has nothing to do with HTTP:

```
$ telnet localhost 222
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.0
```

You can query your webserver using `telnet`, as it allows you to write plaintext messages to a socket.

Another popular "generic" TCP (and UDP) client (and server) would be `nc`:

```
$ nc localhost 222
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.0

$ nc webserver 80
GET /
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
[...]
```

---

Update, in reply of *telnet is also a protocol different from http, but why can we use http over telnet, but can't over ssh*

The `telnet` client is protocol agnostic. It allows you to read/write, having connected to a TCP server.

HTTP being a protocol based on plain-text messages, you can easily forge HTTP queries using `telnet` or `nc`.

In reply of *What does 'banner from the server' which SSH clients awaits for before proceeding with server host key check?*

The SSH client is not protocol agnostic. The very first thing your ssh client will do after establishing its session to your TCP server, is to wait for a banner message, that should identify OpenSSH server version. Then, checking host key, eventually authenticate, which should open a shell, ... The ssh client is only relevant connecting to ssh servers.

Comment: thanks. (1) telnet is also a protocol different from http, but why can we use http over telnet, but can't over ssh? (2) What does 'banner from the server' which SSH clients awaits for before proceeding with server host key check?

Comment: Telnet is confusing. There is a `telnet` program that uses the telnet protocol. Fortunately the client side of the telnet protocol is passive, i.e. it won't kick in unless the server sends the necessary protocol initialisation, so you can use the `telnet` program to talk to any other plain text stream service.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use ssh to connect to a web server and then send a http request and receive a http response?

No. SSH is more complicated protocol than `telnet`.

- `telnet` is just **text protocol** sending text requests and receiving text responses. There is not encryption involved. It has a lot of common with HTTP (also text protocol with simple request&response messages) so therefore you can use `telnet` to get HTTP responses.
- SSH is binary protocol. Also the protocol is wired in the `ssh` binary so you don't have to care about it (unlike `telnet`, where you need to authenticate using special commands).

You can read the banner, but then the key exchange starts and later on, you would get encrypted packets, which you would have to decrypt somehow to understand what is going on there (and send encrypted packets to get some answers).

```
    telnet localhost 22
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to localhost.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2
    SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2
    
    �\��դ`�   !�����curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1Assh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519lchacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.comlchacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com�umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1�umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1none,zlib@openssh.comnone,zlib@openssh.com
```

> What other programs ...

As already mentioned, `netcat` is a good example, if you want to write raw HTTP requests. Otherwise you can achieve the same with `wget`, `curl` or just with a Developer tools in your browser.

To answer the additional questions:

> (1) telnet is also a protocol different from http, but why can we use http over telnet, but can't over ssh?

It is not *"http over telnet"*. You are still using HTTP protocol but using `telnet` tool. They are text protocols quite without restrictions and you can send *anything* using them.

> (2) What does 'banner from the server' which SSH clients awaits for before proceeding with server host key check?

The server is waiting for *"banner from client"*, formally *client identification string*, as explained in [RFC4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2) describing SSH transport layer. There are many stages before proceeding with server host key check, but it is basically key exchange (the first message shown above).